# Should I scale the bounding boxes after padding?

Tags: neural-networks, object-detection

Say if I have a input feature with length 50 and the ground truth bounding box is [10, 20]. If I pad the input to fixed-length 100 and mask the padding in the model, then in the output, should I make the model to predict the raw bounding box [0.1, 0.2] (relative to the padded length 100) or the scaled box [0.2, 0.4] (relative to the feature length 50)?